SAP SAC Analytical Model cannot be opened
I want to create a model for SAC.
I have an initial CDS view to collect the data like this:
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZWODPROBLEMZZ'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@EndUserText.label: 'Init view warehouse Outbound problems'
define view Z_WAREHOUSE_ODPROBZ as select from /scdl/db_proci_o as outbound
left outer join /scdl/db_proch_o as header on outbound.docid = header.docid
left outer join makt as ItemMasterDescription on ItemMasterDescription.matnr = outbound.productno and ItemMasterDescription.spras = 'E'
left outer join /scwm/aqua as phyStock on phyStock.matid = outbound.productid
left outer join mara as mat on mat.matnr = outbound.productno
left outer join /sapapo/matlwh as matStra on matStra.matid = mat.scm_matid_guid22

{
    ltrim(outbound.docno, '0') as docNr,
    outbound.status_wm as statusWM,
    phyStock.quan as PhyQuan,
    matStra.put_stra as PUTSTRA,
    phyStock.lgpla as StorageBin_1,
    phyStock.coo as COO_item,
    outbound.ocountry as Origin2,
    outbound.itemcat as ITEMCAT,
    outbound.itemtype as ITEMTYPE,
    outbound.refdocno_so as Sales_Order,
    outbound.productno as Product,
    outbound.qty as Quantity,
    outbound.uom as UnitOfMeasure,
    outbound.batchno as BatchNo,
    outbound.ocountry as Regio_Country_of_Origin,
    outbound.status_wm as Status_WM,
    outbound.status_pick as Status_PickNr,
    case 
        when outbound.status_pick = '0' then 'Not Relevant'
        when outbound.status_pick = '1' then 'Not Started'
        when outbound.status_pick = '2' then 'Partially Completed'
        when outbound.status_pick = '7' then 'Overpicking'
        when outbound.status_pick = '9' then 'Completed'
        else outbound.status_pick
    end as Status_Pick,
    case 
        when outbound.status_gi = '0' then 'Not Relevant'
        when outbound.status_gi = '1' then 'Not Started'
        when outbound.status_gi = '2' then 'Partially Completed'
        when outbound.status_gi = '7' then 'Overpicking'
        when outbound.status_gi = '9' then 'Completed'
        else outbound.status_gi
    end as Status_GoodIssue,
    case 
        when outbound.status_compl = '0' then 'Not Relevant'
        when outbound.status_compl = '1' then 'Not Started'
        when outbound.status_compl = '2' then 'Partially Completed'
        when outbound.status_compl = '7' then 'Overpicking'
        when outbound.status_compl = '9' then 'Completed'
        else outbound.status_gi
    end as Status_Compl,
    outbound.doccat as Document_Category,
    outbound.tstfr_act_gi as Actual_GoodIssueDate,
    outbound.tstfr_act_gi_date_wh as Actual_GoodIssueDatedate_wh,
    outbound.tstfr_act_gi_time_wh as Actual_GoodIssueDatetime_wh,
    outbound.tstfr_act_gi_wh as Actual_GoodIssueDate_wh,
    outbound./scwm/procty as Whse_Process_Type,
    outbound./scwm/whno as whNO,
    outbound.zzcoo as Country_of_Origin,
    ItemMasterDescription.maktx as Product_short_Description,
    ltrim(outbound.refitemno_so, '0') as Sales_Order_Item,
    outbound.stock_doccat as Type,
    outbound.stock_docno as Sales_Order_Project,
    outbound.stock_itmno as Sales_Order_Item2,
    outbound.tstfr_pick as Picking_Actual,
    -- 0 = not relevant, 1 = Not Started, 2 = Partially Completed, 7 = Overpicking, 9 = Completed    
    case 
        when outbound.status_pick = '9' and outbound.status_gi = '9' then 'Completed'
        else 'Not Picked'
    end as Picking_Status_GI
}
where header.doctype = 'OUTB'                              
and outbound.status_pick = '1'

I need to make a string aggregration as this is not possible out of the box with CDS views I need to create an ABAP class which references this view and makes the aggregation.
The ABAP class:
CLASS zcl_warehouse_quan DEFINITION
  PUBLIC
  FINAL
  CREATE PUBLIC .

  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES if_amdp_marker_hdb.
    CLASS-METHODS:
    ODPROB FOR TABLE FUNCTION Z_WH_ODPROBZ_TABLE_FUNC.
  PROTECTED SECTION.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
ENDCLASS.



CLASS ZCL_WAREHOUSE_QUAN IMPLEMENTATION.


METHOD ODPROB
        BY DATABASE FUNCTION
        FOR HDB
        LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
        OPTIONS READ-ONLY
        USING ZWODPROBLEMZZ.

            itab_coo =
                SELECT
                    ZWODPROBLEMZZ.mandt as client,
                    ZWODPROBLEMZZ.docNr as docNr,
                    ZWODPROBLEMZZ.Country_of_Origin as restriction,
                    cast(ZWODPROBLEMZZ.quantity as INT) as ODQuantity,
                    ZWODPROBLEMZZ.product as product,
                    sum(ZWODPROBLEMZZ.phyquan) as total_phyquan,
                    STRING_AGG(concat(ZWODPROBLEMZZ.coo_item, concat('-',cast(ZWODPROBLEMZZ.phyquan as INT))), ', ') as coo_x_qty,
                    STRING_AGG(concat(ZWODPROBLEMZZ.storagebin_1, concat('-QTY:',cast(ZWODPROBLEMZZ.phyquan as INT))), ', ') as storageBin_1
                FROM ZWODPROBLEMZZ
                GROUP BY ZWODPROBLEMZZ.mandt,ZWODPROBLEMZZ.docNr,ZWODPROBLEMZZ.Country_of_Origin,ZWODPROBLEMZZ.quantity,ZWODPROBLEMZZ.product;
           RETURN
                SELECT client,
                        docNr,
                        restriction,
                        ODQuantity,
                        product,
                        total_phyquan as total_phyquan,
                        coo_x_qty,
                        storageBin_1
                 FROM :itab_coo
                 GROUP BY client,product,restriction, ODQuantity, docNr,total_phyquan,coo_x_qty,storageBin_1;
    ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

To call this in a CDS view I need to make a table function.
So the main CDS view will call the table function and fetch the data.
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZWHODPROBMAINZ'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@EndUserText.label: 'Main view of OD Problem View'
define view Z_WAREHOUSE_ODPROBZ_MAIN as select from Z_WH_ODPROBZ_TABLE_FUNC as odProb

{
    odProb.docNr as OD, 
    odProb.restriction as Restriction,
    odProb.ODQuantity as ODqty
    sum(odProb.ODQuantity) as ODqty,
    odProb.product as Product,
    odProb.total_phyquan as AvailableQty,
    odProb.coo_x_qty as QTY_X_COO,
    odProb.storageBin_1 as StorageBin_X_QTX
}

After this I make the Cube view like this:
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZWHODPROBQUBEZZ'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@Metadata.ignorePropagatedAnnotations: true
@ObjectModel.usageType.sizeCategory: #XL
@ObjectModel.usageType.serviceQuality: #D
@ObjectModel.usageType.dataClass: #MIXED
@Analytics.dataCategory: #CUBE
@EndUserText.label: 'Cube view for wh outb prob'
define view Z_WAREHOUSE_ODPROBZ_CUBE as select from Z_WAREHOUSE_ODPROBZ_MAIN as odProb
{
    odProb.OD as OD, 
    odProb.Restriction as Restriction,
    odProb.ODqty as ODqty
    odProb.Product as Product,
    odProb.AvailableQty as AvailableQty,
    odProb.QTY_X_COO as QTY_X_COO,
    odProb.StorageBin_X_QTX as StorageBin_X_QTX
}

Then the analytical query view:
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZWHODPROBQUERYZ'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #NOT_REQUIRED
@VDM.viewType: #CONSUMPTION
@Analytics.query: true
@EndUserText.label: 'Qube view for wh outb prob'
define view Z_WAREHOUSE_ODPROBZ_QUERY as select from Z_WAREHOUSE_ODPROBZ_CUBE as odProb
{
    @AnalyticsDetails.query.axis: #ROWS
    odProb.OD as OD, 
    @AnalyticsDetails.query.axis: #ROWS
    odProb.Restriction as Restriction,
    @AnalyticsDetails.query.axis: #COLUMNS
    odProb.ODqty as ODqty
    @AnalyticsDetails.query.axis: #ROWS
    odProb.Product as Product,
    @AnalyticsDetails.query.axis: #ROWS
    odProb.AvailableQty as AvailableQty,
    @AnalyticsDetails.query.axis: #COLUMNS
    odProb.QTY_X_COO as QTY_X_COO,
    @AnalyticsDetails.query.axis: #ROWS
    odProb.StorageBin_X_QTX as StorageBin_X_QTX
}

Ok so when I run this directly in eclipse this is the result, all fine:

Now the problem:
When uploading into SAC referenced as a Live Data Connection Model I am not able to create the model, there is an error:


The datasource query has no measures.
Correlation ID: 30858743-2182-4505-8882-271664747438

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'type')
Correlation ID: 38480528-0025-4608-a156-613481472482



The first error "no measures" is funny because actually there is a measure the quantity? Or what is the problem?
The second error is strange.
My question is, is it possible to handle ABAP classes and CDS views in combination or do I need to be aware of something?
Thanks for any help!
